# Playing fragmented video stream(MPEG-DASH) using Python

Tags: python, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, multimedia, mpeg

recently, I'm working on MPEG-DASH, which can generated the fragmented video files and the ****.MPD**** file for getting the fragmented videos.
The fragmented video file is segmented and saved into ***.m4s*** formate, which is the video file without the header(video information).

I'm wondering if I can decode and play the fragmented video using python.

I've tested some of the video play methods, such as ****cv2.VideoCapture****, however, they cannot read the video file without the header.

Really looking forward for your guys advices.

PS: Surely, using the VLC player or other players can play the MPEG-DASH video, however, I wanna decode the fragmented video on python.

Comment: Please add more info on libraries you have used, and include code that you have tried.

Comment: I only tried cv2.VideoCapture

Comment: The "header" is the initialisation segment, which is listed in the MPD. Try appending that to the start of the video file before you feed it into whatever viedo play method you are trying.